# Recover correct value from unstable memory through read operation

Tags: flipflop, memory, register, error-correction, read

We are given a memory with 32-bit width for each word. it has the length (N - number of rows) which is not relevant for the question. we know that the memory has a problem where at any row, one bit could be replaced with a different value (it's not necessarily that all rows must have this unintended
wrong replacement).
What can we do for the memory (by adding FF's, Gates, etc.) in order to detect while reading from memory if we have a wrong value for a certain bit? and what can we do in order to recover the correct value?

my approach was that when we write something to that memory, to do XOR operation on all the bits and save it at some register, then if a bit changes, we can perform XOR again on the read value and compare it with the value saved at that register, if they are unequal then we detected an error.
I'm just not sure this is the right thing to do, and I don't know yet how to draw a schematic for such circuit. I would be glad for some insight.

Comment: google `memory crc ecc`